# laravelcollective form POST not reaching store action

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravelcollective

I am trying to store data from my form through POST but it does not reach my store action, i have tried several methods both none worked for me yet.

**Store method in ContactController:**

```
public function store(StoreMessage $request)
    {
        Log::info('Storing message: '.$request);
        Message::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phonenumber' => $request->phonenumber,
            'text' => $request->text
        ]);
    }
```

**View:**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ContactController@store']) !!}
            {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}

            {!! Form::submit('Creëer de activiteit!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'createSubmit')) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index');
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@store');
```

**Here is the StoreMessage request:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreMessage extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check form action URL from view source and confirm its same.

Comment: <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Comment: yes, seems good, I guess you're using request validation, are you sure you've created `StoreMessage` request ?

Comment: just posted it.

Comment: Can you try normal request like this, `Request $request`, and check if it's working or not

Comment: strange, I tried that as well and it didn't work before iirc, but it does work now. Thanks!

Comment: Just posted same as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try normal request like this, `Request $request`, and check if it's working or not.

You can also use validation with `$request` like below code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'text' => 'required',
     ];
     $this->validate($request,$rules);
     Log::info('Storing message: '.$request);
     Message::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phonenumber' => $request->phonenumber,
        'text' => $request->text
     ]);
}
```